# image slicing, only saves (via Filesaver.js) last slice in sequence

Tags: javascript, canvas, filesaver.js

Hi I'm writing a function to break up a large image into individual smaller tiles, and save the tiles locally via Filesaver.js. However, for some reason, the for-loop keeps writing only the last tile in. For example, if I have a image
and break it up into 4 blocks, and only decide to write out two blocks in the first row, both saved image tiles display the 2nd image tile.

I also write out the block number into the image name (TestImage_0.jpg & TestImage_1.jpg), but both tile image names are TestImage_1.jpg. I have no clue why!, even tried [context.clearRect](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clearrect.asp), but no success. Can someone please help me out here with this silly problem? Here is my function:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var TileWidthpx = parseInt(document.getElementById("HorizPPT").value);
var TileHeightpx = parseInt(document.getElementById("VertPPT").value);
canvas.setAttribute('width', TileWidthpx);
canvas.setAttribute('height', TileHeightpx);

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{   
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(CoverageImg,i*TileWidthpx,0,TileWidthpx,TileHeightpx,0,0,TileWidthpx,TileHeightpx); 

    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){saveAs(blob,'TestImage_'+i+'.jpg');}, "image/jpg");

    alert('done: '+i);
}
```

Even though the alert displays the correct 'i' value of the loop... 
Please, anybody, is it some javascript async-problem that I'm missing (also converted the algorithm to a Promise, but that didn't solve anything)

Answer (score 0):

So it was javascript's async functionality that made everything weird. Eventually got the tile generating algorithm correct by creating a repetitive function and adding delays (important) in the function, with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop). Also had to pass the row and column values so that the correct template position could be generated. Here's my resulting code:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var TileWidthpx = parseInt(document.getElementById("HorizPPT").value);
    var TileHeightpx = parseInt(document.getElementById("VertPPT").value);
    canvas.setAttribute('width', TileWidthpx);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', TileHeightpx);

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');      

    var col = 0; //variable for columns
    var row = 0;
    var ColCount = 2;
    var RowCount = 2;
    Loop(col,row,ColCount,RowCount);    //call delayed loop for first time
    function Loop (COL,ROW,ColCount,RowCount)   //repetitive function
    {    
        setTimeout(function () 
        {    
            context.beginPath();
            context.drawImage(CoverageImg,COL*TileWidthpx,ROW*TileHeightpx,TileWidthpx,TileHeightpx,0,0,TileWidthpx,TileHeightpx); 
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob){saveAs(blob,'TestImage_C'+COL+'_R'+ROW+'.png');}, "image/png");
            context.closePath();
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);   
            COL++;  

            if(COL == ColCount)
            {
                COL = 0;
                ROW++;
            }
            if(ROW < RowCount)                  
                Loop(COL,ROW,ColCount,RowCount);  //repeat function while below Col threshold    

        }.bind(this), 2000) //function delayed with 2 seconds*/
    }
```

Hope this helps whomever gets stuck with the same annoying problem...